# how to get crash report when app rejected by app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, crash-reports

I had submitted my first app to the App Store last friday. after one week,unfortunately, they rejected my app cause it seems to crash in some weird situations.
I had tried my app on 4 different iPhones before I submit it to the App Store also I got 4 different people to test it with out me telling them what to do and it never had crashed....

finally, they have provided me with 5 .plist files but I don't know how to use these files.
Can someone help me with this, please?